# Why is a cast required for byte subtraction in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, integer, byte

I have to following code in VS2008 .net 3.5 using WinForms:

```
byte percent = 70;
byte zero = 0;

Bitmap copy = (Bitmap)image1.Clone();
...

Color oColor = copy.GetPixel(x, y);
byte oR = (byte)(oColor.R - percent < zero ? zero : oColor.R - percent);
```

When I leave the "**`(byte)`**" off the last line of code, I get a compiler error saying it "Cannot implicitly convert type '`int`' to '`byte`'." If everything is of type `byte` and `byte` is an integer type... then why do I need to have the cast?

Comment: Eric Lippert says, "I don't think of bytes as "numbers"; I think of them as patterns of bits that could be _interpreted_ as numbers, or characters, or colors or whatever. If you're going to be doing math on them and treating them as numbers, then it makes sense to move the result into a data type that is more commonly interpreted as a number." See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why-c .

Comment: You guys do realize you've marked this as a duplicate even though it was asked *before* the "already has an answer here" link?

Comment: Hell, now it even says "asked before" even though the other question was asked three years later.

Comment: Uh, actually, *every* data value is a bit pattern that can be interpreted as a number.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because subtraction is coercing up to an integer.  As I recall, byte is an unsigned type in C#, so subtraction can take you out of the domain of bytes.

Comment: Subtraction can take you out of the domain of every number type. That doesn't really explain why there is no byte-specific subtraction operator.

Comment: Well, then, the answer is "because the developers of C# decided they didn't want one."

Answer (score 11):

That's because the result of a byte subtraction doesn't fit in a byte:

```
byte - byte = (0..255) - (0..255) = -255..255
```

Comment: What a nice graphic explanation !!!

Comment: Neither does any integer type except floats or decimals. int is of finite range too, so (min_int - max_int) wont fit, but it returns an int.

Comment: @Adam: 1) floats and decimals are not integer types. 2) Results of subtractions for these also may not fit, as these also have a finite (though large) range.

Answer (score 8):

[Arithmetic on bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693(VS.71).aspx) results in an int value by default.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @Timothy Cartner, Link only answers are not recommended on SO,
For the reason it stands now for a year, with a broken link.
Could you provide some context?

Answer (score 4):

Because arithmetic on bytes returns integers by default so of the two possible assignments the narrower type of zero (byte) is promoted to int (that of oColor.r - percent). Thus the type of the operation is an int. The compiler will not, without a cast, allow you to assign a wider type to a narrower type, because it's a lossy operation. Hence you get the error, unless you explicitly say "I know I'm losing some data, it's fine" with the cast.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `byte` subtraction returns an `int`.  Actually any binary arithmetic operations on `bytes` will return an `int`, so the cast is required.

Answer (score 2):

Because arithmetic operations on sbyte, byte, ushort, and short are automatically converted to int. The most plausible reason for this is that such operations are likely to overflow or underflow.

Thus, in your ternary operation, the final oColor.R - percent, actually results in an int, not a byte. So the return type of the operation is int.

Answer (score 1):

Because the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default.  In your example `percent` defaults to `int`.  You can read more about it on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

FWIW, java also promotes bytes to int.