# Compilation error during Bit shift "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte' "

Tags: c#

I am getting following Error. I tried all types of typecasting but no help. Please let me know what is going on here.

```
Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

byte[] bitVector = new byte[UInt32.MaxValue/8];

//bitVector[((UInt32)x/8)]  |=  (1 << ((int)(x % 8))); ERROR 
//bitVector[((UInt32)x / 8)] |= (1 << Convert.ToByte(x % 8)); ERROR
bitVector[((UInt32)x/8)]  |=  (1 << 5); //No Error
```

Comment: What is definition of bitVector array

Comment: @Mrinal Kamboj I edited my question. It is Byte[]

Comment: Almost duplicate -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123788/whats-wrong-with-this-expression-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-byte, feel free to find exact duplicate that explains types  accepted/returned by shift operators (hint: byte is not one of those). Note that rules for compile time constants are different and would be covered by some other duplicate (for your last line of sample).

Answer (score 1):

Following shall help

```
bitVector[((UInt32)x/8)]  |=  (byte)(1 << x % 8)
```

Result of the `bit` operation  is `integer` and you are trying to fill it in `byte` type, therefore it needs an explicit typecast

Comment: Thanks for responding. I get following error. "Operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'uint'"

Comment: What's the type of x ?

Comment: Ok your x is uint type, then you need to make the following modification:

(byte)(1 << (int)(x % 8)). Typecast the (x%8) to integer explicitly

Comment: Glad to help :), please mark as answer, it it resolves the issue at hand

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this

bitVector[((UInt32)x / 8)] |= ((byte)1 << (1 % 8));

The two that are giving you trouble are doing so because you are trying assign an int (the result of the byte shift) to a byte array, by forcing the constant that you are shifting to a byte you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I still get the error as soon as I use this (x % 8). Note that I want (x % 8), not (1 % 8)