# LINQ aggregate functions on bytes, shorts, and unsigned values

Tags: c#, linq

How would you go about using LINQ aggregate functions (ex. Sum, Average) on collections of bytes, shorts, and unsigned values?  Granted, I'm a new C# programmer, but I can't even figure out how to get something that compiles let alone has proper output.

Here's a trivial example of what I am trying to do:

```
short[] numbersArray = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
short sumArray = numbersArray.Sum();
```

or

```
List<short> numbersList = new List<short> { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
short sumList = numbersList.Sum();
```

I can't either of these samples to work.  If I change the data type to int it works, but I can't get it to work for shorts, bytes, uints, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Enumerable.Sum<T>()` is only defined for `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` in

```
double,
double?
int,
int?
decimal,
decimal?
long,
long?
float,
float?
```

This is because there is no addition operator<sup>*</sup> for `short` or any of the other primitive types (`short + short` is `int`, for example).

You have to say:

```
short[] numbersArray = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int sumArray = numbersArray.Sum(x => (int)x);
```

and less explicitly you can get away with

```
short[] numbersArray = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int sumArray = numbersArray.Sum(x => x);
```

In this case, you are now invoking the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx):

```
int Enumerable.Sum<short>(
    this IEnumerable<short> source,
    Func<short, int> selector
)
```

<sup>*</sup>: Here I mean "operator" in the sense of an function `F:(short x short) -> short`.

Comment: +1 good observation, but why did they make it like that, is there any reason? My be to avoid checking of overflow?

Comment: @Akash: Most all C based languages have automatic promotion to `int` before any arithmetic happens. You'd probably have to go all the way back to K&R to find that one.

Comment: Not so much to avoid checking of overflow, but you can overflow very quickly with short. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem

Answer (score 5):

`Enumerable.Sum` [accepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) either `int`s, `long`s, `single`s or `double`s.

You can cast the numbers to make them eligible as the parameter:

```
short [] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int sum = numbers.Cast<int> ().Sum ();
```

As an alternative, you can [provide a `Func<TSource, int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184.aspx) lambda that selects `int`s for you:

```
short [] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
int sum = numbers.Sum (x => x); // lambda type is inferred as Func<short, int>
```

I declare `sum` as `int` because **it's really unsafe to think a sum of `short`s is a `short` itself**.
It is even reflected in the fact that [you have to do explicit casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when adding `short`s:

```
int sum = a + b; 
short shortSum = (short)(a + b); // you can use an explicit casting to get short
```

So **if you're certain you're not going to overflow, just cast the result**:

```
short shortSum = (short) numbers.Cast<int> ().Sum ();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Sum` extension method doesn't have an overload that takes an `IEnumerable<short>`.

Instead, you can pass a lambda expression that implicitly converts the `short`s to `int`s:

```
short sumList = (short)numbersList.Sum(i=>i);
```

Answer (score 0):

This confused me, but I was able to make it work like:

```
List<short> li = new List<short> {1,2,3,4,5};
short l = (short)li.Sum(i => i);
```