# short + short != short?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, short

Version: Visual Studio Professional 2013 Update 4  
Build param: Prefer 32-bit is true

I don't understand the error in the following C# code:

```
short iCount = 20;
short iValue = iCount + (short)1;
```

Adding a short to an int casted to a short results in the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The above error, also seen in the following case, is perfectly valid here:

```
short iCount = 20;
short iValue = iCount + 1;
```

The following workaround removes the error:

```
short iCount = 20;
short iValue = (short)(iCount + 1);
```

So addition in the form "short + Int32 constant" apparently works and the result is Int32, which needs to be cast to a short.

Is there an explanation why the first code sample fails or is this a compiler bug? (which I can hardly believe after 4 Updates)

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504837/why-is-my-addition-of-2-shorts-causing-a-casting-compile-error-due-to-ints)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3080381/335858)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853602/c-sharp-does-not-let-me-sum-two-shorts-to-a-short)

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065287/why-is-ushort-ushort-equal-to-int

Comment: Modern architectures are built for 32- or 64-bit arithmetic. It's simply more efficient for the `+` operator to "promote" 16-bit int's to 32-bit and then do 32-bit addition, with a 32-bit result. Though perhaps unexpected, it is by design, as specified in the [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691329%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: However if the expression is constant (known at compile-time), the conversion from `int` to `short` is "free". As in: `const int iCount = 20; short iValue = iCount + 1;` Note that both summands are of type `int`, so clearly the sum is an `int` too, but the conversion from `int` to `short` is implicit in these cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Int is the smallest signed type for which the + operator is defined, so trying to use + on a short results in that kind of error.

Comment: Interesting! A more complete answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem/4347752#4347752)