# division of short returns int c# (short/short=int ?!)

Tags: c#, division, short

I'm trying the following:

```
short value1 = 4;
short value2 = 2;
short result = value1 / value2;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Is there no such thing as division for short?
Is there a reason why short/short returns an int or just because?
The reason I'm wondering, is because I can divide int's eventhough its limitations (cast back from float)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators

Comment: You need to cast the result back down to `short`: `short result = (short)(value1 / value2);`

Comment: `value1 / value2` will return an `int` type.

Comment: JHBonarius, no im aware of that. I wonder why short division returns int rather than short

Comment: alright, thanks :) so there is only float division

Comment: @julianbechtold No, there is float division and integer division - but there is no short division because shorts are promoted to ints before performing the calculation.

Comment: my bad. Didn't read the dupe properly. @Slate the anwer is in the leading text you link: you should put that in an anwer. I couldn't find a good dupe, so this could be the new reference.

Comment: I'm thinking this essentially has the answer, even though it deals with adding shorts, not dividing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504837/why-is-my-addition-of-2-shorts-causing-a-casting-compile-error-due-to-ints

Comment: The actual answer is in the link posted by Slate, from which I quote: `In the case of integral types, [division is] defined for the int, uint, long, and ulong types. When operands are of other integral types (sbyte, byte, short, ushort, or char), their values are converted to the int type, which is also the result type of an operation`. This doesn't answer WHY the language was designed that way, of course, but it does answer the question `Is there no such thing as division for short?`

Answer (score 2):

You are absolutely right:

When you divide two `int` numbers (between -2147483648 and 2147483647), the result will mostly be between the same boundaries, so the division result should be `int`, which is correct.

When you divide two `short` numbers (between -32768 and 32767), the result will mostly be between the same boundaries, so the division result should be `short`, while it is `int`, so this is wrong.

Also [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-division) is wrong: it mentions the integer division being **an** integer type, while it clearly is not just **an** integer type, but **the** integer type.

By the way: there is one ±fault in my explanation (hence the "mostly"):

(-32768) / (-1) is not within the `short` boundaries, but what the heck:
(-2147483648) / (-1) is also not within the `int` boundaries!

Comment: Context is important - the section is talking about Integer division as opposed to Floating point division. It therefore also describes the division of uints (Uint32), longs (Int64) and ulong (UInt64), which is separately defined from int (Int32) type.
Doing var x = 4L / 2L will give you a long, not an int.

Comment: @Slate: there are integer types for which the integer division is correctly defined, but for the `short` type, this is not the case, hence my answer.

Comment: My comment was at your statement of "the documentation is wrong: it mentions the integer division being an integer type, while it clearly is not just an integer type, but the integer type.", which is incorrect as the docs refer to other integer types