# two shorts added together don't equal a short?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer summing blues, short += short problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem)

I feel dumb that this is happening, but I have never had this happen before. I am trying to do the following:

```
foreach (short a in answers)
{
     if (a != myConstants.NOTCOMPLETE_SHORT)
     {
         result = result + a;
     }
     else
     {
         empty = true;
         break;
     }
}
```

answers is an array of shorts. intellisense is telling me that result + a is an int and I can't assign it to a short.

I have to be missing something very fundamental here but not allowing two shorts to be added together and assigned to a short variable just seems weird.

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer here as to why this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since a `short` is a 16bit Integer, if you added, say, `32,000` and `32,000` (both valid `short`s), you'd get `64,000` which is not a valid `short` as `Int16.MaxValue` is `32767`.

Thus, the addition operator must return a 32bit Int to prevent the result from possibly overflowing.

**UPDATE:**

For fun, I just tried this in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> ([System.Int32]::MaxValue + [System.Int32]::MaxValue).GetType().Name
Double

PS C:\> (10000000 + 10000000).GetType().Name
Int32
```

So looks like an `Int32` *can* cast to a `Double` if needed.

I'm gonna go out on a limb and say *bounds checking* during addition is more expensive, and thus should only be done if there's a likely chance of an overflow (like two bytes or two shorts) especially when they're possibly using the same amount of memory anyway. I think that's just the way the language was designed.

Comment: I had the same thought but then I could apply the same logic to ints, that if I added two ints together the value might be larger than int so I would have to assign it to a bigint.

Comment: definitely think is a correct reason for returning an int since an addition could* result in a value needing more than 16bits...but why does must* apply to addition with shorts but not ints? genuine ly curious

Comment: Also I'm mistaken, Int16.MaxValue is actually 32767 :)

Comment: @peroija - In my tests, it seems `Int32` can cast to a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic could wrap around ( to -ve values ) if the result is greater than the largest possible short value. Since it is more **likely** that this will happen with short, and since int has a larger range, short + short is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Either overload `operator+=` or change the code so that:

```
short a = 6000;
short b = 6000;
result = (short) result + a //answer 12,000
```

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated in the other answers, there are good reasons why two shorts make an int. The addition assignment operator *+=* overload returns a short so your code would become:

```
foreach (short a in answers)
{
    if (a == myConstants.NOTCOMPLETE_SHORT)
    {
         empty = true;
         break;
    }
    result += a;
}
```