# Not obvious type conversion: x = (x + xstep < xmax ? x + xstep : xmax)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

given the following Code:

```
    byte x, xmin, xmax, xstep;
    x = (x + xstep < xmax ? x + xstep : xmax)
```

the compiler tells me

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Where does the conversion from byte to int happen? And why?

Comment: (x + xstep) returns an integer, as it could overflow a byte

Comment: @DanBryant: Why post that as a comment? If that's true, it's an *answer*.

Comment: see [byte (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the msdn

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer summing blues, short += short problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem)

Comment: possible duplicate of [byte + byte = int... why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a `byte` to a `byte` results in an `int`, according to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Consider, for example, the following two byte variables x and y:
>
> ```
>     byte x = 10, y = 20;
> ```
>
> The following assignment statement will produce a compilation error, because the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default.
>
> ```
>     // Error: conversion from int to byte:
>     byte z = x + y;
> ```
>
> To fix this problem, use a cast:
>
> ```
>     // OK: explicit conversion:
>     byte z = (byte)(x + y);
> ```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize that they defined a different behaviour for byte, as int ia, ib = int.MaxValue, ic = int.MaxValue; ia = ib + ic; compiles and produces the expected overflow.

Comment: @Vertigo: The difference is: people are *highly likely* to be working with byte values that overflow a byte when added, and *highly unlikely* to be working with int values that overflow when added. If you are working with ints that big then you should be using longs in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Break it down. We have

```
sum = expression
```

Sum is of type byte. What is the type of expression? Break it down. Expression is

```
summand1 + summand2
```

Summand1 is of type byte. What type is summand2? Break it down. It is:

```
test ? consequence : alternative
```

Test is of type bool. Alternative is of type byte. What type is consequence?  Break it down! It is:

```
summand3 + summand4
```

That's byte + byte.  Byte + byte is int, so consequence is of type int.

Now we have enough information to work out the type of summand2.  Consequence is int, alternative is byte, and int is the more general of those two types. (Because every byte is convertible to int but not every int is convertible to byte.)

Therefore the type of summand2 is int.  So we have sum equal to a byte plus an int. Byte plus int is int, and therefore we have int assigned to byte. Which is an explicit conversion, not an implicit conversion.

Comment: What was probably not known by Vertigo is that byte + byte is int

Comment: Exactly that. Thought that byte + byte would, same as int + int, perform no type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
byte x, xmin, xmax, xstep;
// assign your variables x, xmin, xmax, and xstep,
// then...
x = ((x + xstep) < xmax) ? (byte)(x + xstep) : xmax;
```

You only need to cast that one part, probably because it *could* exceed a `byte` size, but I don't know.

...or really care why. :)

According to T.J. up there, adding a `byte` to a `byte` produces an `int`, so I guess that's the real answer.

But, my version compiles with no complaints with only the one cast.

Comment: It fails on what, @DavidHeffernan? I just got it to compile in VS2010 before posting this. Not 1 complaint.

Comment: Fair enough, didn't see the cast. But I don't see how this answers the Q. I mean the Q was not, how do I cast, but why do I need to cast?

Comment: It says the post by T.J. Crowder explains why it is not allowed, and shows where the one cast would be needed to make it work. That said, you may have a point. I did not run the code, so I do not know what behavior the compiler exhibits when the bytes are added together.