# Difference between a+=1 and a=a+1 in C#

Tags: c#

I found out that in C# a+=1 is not equal to a = a+1.

For example, the following code compiles without any error:
byte b = 10;
b += 5;

while the following code has a compilation error:
byte b = 10;
b = b + 5;

Can somebody let me know why?

Comment: The error message is always helpful

Comment: The error message is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `b + 5` becomes an integer ( Int32) ( mainly because there is possibility of overload)

And the compound assignment specification states below:

> Otherwise, if the selected operator is a predefined operator, if the
>   return type of the selected operator is explicitly convertible to the
>   type of x, and if y is implicitly convertible to the type of x or the
>   operator is a shift operator, then the operation is evaluated as **x =
>   (T)(x op y)**, where T is the type of x, except that x is evaluated only
>   once.

Answer (score 1):

Because `b += 5` is compiled as if it read `b = (byte)(b + 5)`. The cast takes care of the conversion to the proper type, so there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is probably treating the 5 as an Int32 in the second one.  You'll need to cast it