# Arithmetic operations with 8 and 16 bit integers

Tags: c#, int, short

I do understand why this produce compile time-error:

```
short x = 1;
short y = 2;
short z = x + y; // compile-time error
```

I've grasped why this runs without any issues:

```
short x = 1;
short y = 2;
x += y; // all right, because of c# specs section 7.17.2
```

But I've got no clue why this also works:

```
short x = (short)1 + (short)2;
```

I expected to get the same compile-time error as  in the first example, but it runs successfully... Why?

Comment: Perhaps because in your last example, the compiler detects a constant value?

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate of the linked post - the OP specifically called out the behavior in that post... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem)

Comment: + operator will return whatever type is on the (right/left??) I forget which one but since you have the same type on both sides of + it returns that type.

Comment: @RadioSpace that's not necessarily true.  In C#, short + short returns an int.

Comment: It is really the other way around.  It wants a cast because the expression can overflow so easily in an undetectable way and wants you to acknowledge that you thought about that problem.  They could not think of a decent syntax to enforce the cast for +=.  These casts are not necessary in VB.NET but it checks for overflow by default.  Which is "better" but it is very expensive.  Not the C# way.

Comment: @RadioSpace: There's no such rule.  The smaller operand promotes to the size of the bigger one, or `int` if both are smaller.  C++ has the same rule, btw, but also has an implicit conversion back to the smaller size so it is only a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using constant values, the compiler can detect that it's allowable, evaluate *it at compile time*, and let it execute.  The generated IL evaluates to the same as typing `short x = 3;`.

Note the following also works (for the same reason):

```
const short x = 1;
const short y = 2;
short z = x + y;
```

But this fails:

```
const short x = 32000;
const short y = 32001;
short z = x + y;
```

Note that this is covered in the C# Language Spec, 6.1.9 Implicit constant expression conversions:

- A constant-expression (§7.19) of type int can be converted to type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant-expression is within the range of the destination type.

Answer (score 2):

Your last snippet just compiles to constant `3`. Compiler doesn't need to call any operators in `int` it just computes and stores the value at compile time.

it is same as `short x = 3;`

Here is the generated IL

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3    //Load the constant 3 into evaluation stack
IL_0002:  stloc.0     // stores the value in stack to x
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've got no clue why this also works:
>
> ```
> short x = (short)1 + (short)2;
> ```

The compiler evaluates the rhs expression at compile time and can prove that the result is within bounds.

Comment: What about `short x = 1 + 2;` ?  Should still output an `int` which can be proven at compile time to fit in `short`.

Comment: @BenVoigt that works fine, provided you use literals (constants)