# Cast error in C# for datatype short

Tags: c#, type-conversion

A basic question about int and short in C#

Why am I getting a syntax error for this code:

```
for (short i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
{
      short key = i + (short)1; //This is where I get error
                                //Can not implicitly convert 'int' to 'short'
      //Some more code, dealing with this key...
}
```

And is there a good table somewhere showing the different types with their initializer shortcuts?

(like `var f = 1M;` will compile to decimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the following,

```
short key = i + (short)1;
```

to

```
short key = (short) (i + (short)1);
```

The reason being, any additions of short + short might overflow short range. and hence this requires a explicit casting.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an answer to this part of the question as well?  
"And is there a good table somewhere showing the different types with their initializer shortcuts?

(like var f = 1M; will compile to decimal)"

Comment: No Thomas, I can't find a single location where you can get a consolidated results. The closest link that i found is this one - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
short key = (short) (i + (short)1);
```

Also note that `Int16` variables are converted into Int32 when you are adding them.

You can also read Eric Liperts answer:

- [Integer summing blues, short += short problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem/4347752#4347752)

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an answer to this part of the question as well? "And is there a good table somewhere showing the different types with their initializer shortcuts? (like var f = 1M; will compile to decimal)"

Comment: @thomas:- I didnt get that. Can you ask a seperate question for that elaborating more on it?