# Why are there assignment operators (&=, +=) but no non-assignment operators (&, +) for short primitives?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, operators, assignment-operator

I stumbled upon the behavior that bitwise or arithmetic operations are not allowed on primitive types smaller than 32 bit, but the respective assignment operations are in fact allowed:

```
short BitwiseAnd(short a, short b) { return a & b; }         // error
short BitwiseAndAssignment(ref short a, short b) { a &= b; } // works

short Add(short a, short b) { return a + b; }                // error
short AddAssignment(ref short a, short b) { a += b; }        // works
```

The same behavior holds for other short primitive types like `byte`, `sbyte`, and `ushort`.

I understand that arithmetic and logical operations are defined for 32-bit and larger types (`int`, `long`...) because it's what the processor provides ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)), and shorter types are widened and can be casted back to 8 or 16 bit. However, is there a reason why this would work in an assignment operator? First I assumed that behind the scenes, the `short`s are casted to `int`, but then you would have an assignment/return value `short value = (some int)`, which should yield an error since the cast is not implicit.

*On a different note*: I tried out some code in Visual Studio's immediate window, but there, a lot more code seems to work. The immediate window probably does some implicit casting which would usually be explicit. E.g., `short a = (int)5;` is allowed in the immediate window. So that's not helping.

Comment: short Add(short a, short b) { return (short)(a + b); }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343624/integer-summing-blues-short-short-problem

Comment: re `short a = (int)5;` in the immediate window - that works in regular C# too; here the values `5` and `(int)5` can be processed and understood entirely at compile time as constant expressions; the compiler checks that these constant expressions don't overflow, etc, and allows it. Conversely, if you do `short a = (int)50000000;`, the compiler breaks at **compile time** (not runtime) with a [CS0031](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879y0b2y(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: I see, thanks! I didn't notice the compile-time constant substitution. It's just different because of the syntactic context, which made it work in the immediate window but not in my actual code (as it can't be replaced by a constant expression there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, is there a reason why this would work in an assignment operator?

Yes: because otherwise the assignment operator *could never work* for these types - there would be no syntax that allowed it to work. The *expectation* of `a += b` or `a &= b` is clear, so the conversion is performed automatically.

With `a + b` or `a & b`, as you already note: this is widened for performance reasons; syntax exists to put it back, specifically `(short)(a+b)` etc.

Comment: Can you expand this *expectation* thing? Because for my expectation, when the `+` operator is not defined, I definintely would not assume that `+=` is defined. So I would *expect* that there is no syntax to make it work.

Comment: @hschmauder in C#, assignment operators **cannot** be explicitly overloaded; they are implicitly overloaded using the binary operators. Meaning: if `+` is supported, so is `+=`, interpreted as `a += b;` => `a = (AType)(a + b);`

Comment: "widened for performance reasons" seems like a dubious claim to me. I doubt the impact is big, especially since the JITter could widen transparently in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

The real error is due to implicit conversion of smaller integral types to `int` when you are doing operations on them.

When you have `a & b` where `a` and `b` are `short`s, they both are converted to int and the `&` operator applies and the result will be of type `int` so you can not return `int` as `short` in your method declaration. a simple cast will solve the problem. `(short)(a & b)`.

```
short BitwiseAnd(short a, short b) { return (short)(a & b); }  //no error!
```

When you have

```
short BitwiseAndAssignment(ref short a, short b) { a &= b; }
```

compiler will generate the cast for you , if not you can not ever use these kind of operators (`+=`, `*=`, ... ) on smaller types than `int`.

---

**What happens under the hood??**

```
short a = 1;
short b = 2;

short c = a + b; //error!
```

Why? because + operator does not have an overload to receive two `short` parameter. Since implicit conversion between `short` and `int` exists then the method resolution will choose the overload that has two int as input parameters. so it will cast `a` and `b` to `int` and **then call the chosen overload which returns an `int`**. Because it returns an `int` you can not store it in a `short` variable so you need to cast it explicitly.

```
short c = (short)(a + b)//this will work
```

Comment: Ah, thanks to your answer I understood Marc's answer on unavailable syntax above. Thank you!