# C# what can't I see ? (UInt16 conversion)

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

This is driving me nuts...
Incoming hex strings from a Dictionary object - they all seem to be ok as 'strings', but I've tried several methods to return the values in those fields...
Ended up with this expanded code to find the issue.

```
for (UInt16 i = 0; i < Convert.ToUInt16(addressList["NUM_ALIAS"],16); i++)
{
    // loop through all blocked values
    UInt16 blockSize = Convert.ToUInt16(addressList["LEN_ALIAS_FROM"], 16);
    UInt16 blockBase = Convert.ToUInt16(addressList["ALIASFROM"], 16);
    UInt16 blockAddr = blockBase + (i * blockSize);

    // use the values
    :::
}
```

The syntax checker indicates an error -underlining- >>>**blockBase + (i * blockSize)**<<<

ERROR: ***Cannot implicitly convert type int to ushort***

Thoughts appreciated - and I can learn something!
FLAGGED AS DUPLICATE?  I can't see it anywhere else with my issue.
((Can mod please link to the duplicate so I/we can see it ?))
Aah - ok the duplicate was shown up the top *after* I opened it for editing and saved it.

Comment: please add addressList values as well in question.

Comment: `short * short` evaluates to an `int` for the same reason `short + short` evaluates to an `int`, which is explained in [Integer summing blues, short += short problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4343624/3744182).  You need to do `UInt16 blockAddr = checked((short)(blockBase + (i * blockSize)));`.  The [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) makes sure you don't have an overflow.