# What is the difference between seed+=(char)1; and seed = seed + (char)1;

Tags: c#

I'm Running the following program in C #  :

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        char seed = 'a';
        char EndValue='z';
        while ( seed <= EndValue){
            Console.WriteLine(seed);
            seed+=(char)1;   
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but changing the `seed+=(char)1;` to `seed = seed + (char)1;`

It throws error

> exit status 1
>
> main.cs(9,8): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to` char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
> Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings" in repl.it

https://repl.it/@nkshschdv/iteration-over-char-variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [byte + byte = int... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)

Comment: @Jay Are you ok?

Comment: It's 'Okay' I think and am I yes

Comment: This question has been asked before.
Please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254098/is-a-b-operator-of-char-implemented-same-as-a-a-b

Comment: You can use `seed = (char)(seed + (char)1);`

Comment: `for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) { Console.WriteLine(c); }` is a far more obvious way to write this, and avoids any conversion warnings.

Comment: `seed++;` would be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Lets have a look at what your code is actually doing.
If `i` is an int

`i += 1` is the same as `i = i + 1`

So in your case 
`seed+=(char)1;` is the same as `seed = (char)(seed + 1);`

So `seed = seed + (char)1;` is just missing the char conversion which is implicit in the way you are doing it.

You can also write it `seed = (char)((int)seed + 1);` but C# handles the char to int conversion for the + operator automatically. As Dennis_E pointed out, because of this implicit int conversion you can just call `seed++;`