# Cannot use the XOR operator with two char's for some reason, does anyone get why?

Tags: c#, operators

Is there some formal standards that do not allow one to use the ^ or XOR function in C# with two chars?

```
    public char[] XORinput(char[] input, char SN)
    {
        int InputSize = input.Length;
        //initialize an output array
        char[] output = new char[InputSize];

        for (int i = 0; i < InputSize; i++)
        {

            output[i] = input[i] ^ SN;

        }


        return output;

    }
```

For whatever reason this code is giving me this error, Error    1400    Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This does not make any sense.

Caller:

```
                string num = "12345";
                char SN = Convert.ToChar(num);//serial number

                string sCommand = ("Hellow");

                char[] out = new char[sCommand.ToCharArray().Length];


                out = calculator.XORinput(sCommand.ToCharArray(), SN);
```

Comment: What does the caller look like?

Comment: I see the problem, num is not a char, its a char array

Comment: Perhaps you should modify your function to work with bytes / shorts instead.  `char` is 16bit, which is fine on its own, but it is meant to hold UTF-16 non-surrogate characters, you could potentially fill it with a value that cannot be represented by UTF-16.  This could cause problems if you ever try and render that character, if you're never rendering it, then why have a char in the first place?

Comment: In your conversion from string to char array, this is the way to do it: `char[] out = sCommand.ToCharArray(0,sCommand.Length);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xor operator (along with other operators) return an integer result. So a single cast to char is sufficient.

```
output[i] = (char)(input[i] ^ SN);
```

In this case you wouldn't have to cast, but it's less efficient in your case:

```
output[i] = input[i];
output[i] ^= SN;
```

Comment: how come its more efficient to use the latter case?

Comment: @Recurrsion: Because you have to set the value of the array index twice instead of just once.

Comment: First case is more efficient as only one lookup in the output array is needed. Just mentioned the second case as an example of when you can use bitwise operation without needing to cast.

Answer (score 7):

The error is not with the function, but with the result of it.

When you do `input[i] ^ SN;` your result is an int, which you "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'char'.

You can cast it like this:

```
(char)(input[i] ^ SN);
```

Comment: Why does `char ^ char` return `int`, though?

Comment: Because certain operations, such as arithmetic and XOR, are only defined on `int`s in .NET.  The `char`s are implicitly converted to `int`s (so now it's `int ^ int`) so that they can be XORed, which results in an `int` result.

Comment: @TimS.: Thanks for the response. Further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/942349/120955

Answer (score 1):

If you have a character, a char, you can convert it to an integer, an int.

And then you can use the ^ operator to perform XOR on it. You don't appear to be using that operator at the moment, which might be the source of your problem.

```
    output[i] = (char)((uint)input[i] ^ (uint)SN);
```

Comment: That appeared to work, although I am using the ^ if that's what your referring to ?

Comment: The issue I now need to fix is                       string num = "12345";
                char SN = Convert.ToChar(num);//serial number