# Why unchecked not working on byte?

Tags: c#

The `unchecked` keyword has been explained in MSDN library as:

> The unchecked keyword is used to suppress overflow-checking for
>   integral-type arithmetic operations and conversions. In an unchecked
>   context, if an expression produces a value that is outside the range
>   of the destination type, the overflow is not flagged.

By definition it works well on `int` type.

For example:

```
unchecked
{
   int i=2147483647+10;
}
```

Here it suppresses the overflow inside unchecked block.(it should be)

But when we apply it on byte it does not work

```
byte b1=100,b2=100,b3;
unchecked
{
   b3=b1+b2;//error here
}
```

So whatever is written in unchecked environment should be suppressed.

Why it is giving compile time error?

Or does I not understand unchecked keyword at all?

Comment: A `byte` holds up to 255, so that wouldn't overflow anyway. What is your "compiler error"?

Comment: can't implicitly convert int to byte

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've misunderstood the purpose of `unchecked`. It has two effects:

- It prevents overflow checking at execution time
- It allows you to convert *constant* values which are outside the normal range of the type, as per your first example.

It *doesn't* change the type of an expression. The [type of the expression `b1 + b2` is still `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why), so you still need a cast to convert it to `byte`. The difference between `checked` and `unchecked` in this situation is the execution-time handling of overflow when casting the `int` back to `byte`:

```
byte b1 = 255, b2 = 1;
unchecked
{
   byte b3 = (byte) (b1 + b2);
   // b3 is now 0
}
```

With checked arithmetic:

```
byte b1 = 255, b2 = 1;
checked
{
   byte b3 = (byte) (b1 + b2); // OverflowException
}
```

Comment: It is unbeleivable to see Jon Skeet sir give answer to my question ,Thnkkuu sir

Answer (score 4):

There is no [`+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/k1a63xkz.aspx) operation on bytes. So, `b1 + b2` is still `int` as a result.

Your code works as like;

```
byte b1 = 100, b2 = 100, b3;
unchecked
{
   b3 = (int)b1 + (int)b2; //error here
}
```

If you cast to `byte` the solution, there will be no problem;

```
byte b1 = 100, b2 = 100, b3;
unchecked
{
    b3 = (byte)(b1 + b2); //There is no error here.
}
```

> Why unchecked not working on byte?

Because `unchecked` keyword is uses for overflow-checking for integral-type arithmetic and Eric Lippert *[says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why#comment750078_941584)*;

> The various musings below are a reasonable approximation of the design
>   considerations. **More generally: I don't think of bytes as "numbers"**; I
>   think of them as patterns of bits that could be interpreted as
>   numbers, or characters, or colors or whatever. If you're going to be
>   doing math on them and treating them as numbers, then it makes sense
>   to move the result into a data type that is more commonly interpreted
>   as a number.