# C# Combine two 2D byte arrays (Filling in zeros)

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two 2D byte arrays that I want to merge. For example:

```
2D array1:         2D array2:           Combined array3:
[1][0][1]          [0][1][0]            [1][1][1]
[0][0][0]          [1][0][1]     =>     [1][0][1]
[1][0][1]          [0][1][0]            [1][1][1]
```

I tried like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array3.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < array3.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // Missing a cast
        array3[i, j] = array1[i, j] + array2[i, j];
    }
}
```

The line under the comment says it cannot convert to `byte` from `int`. I was reading this: [byte + byte = int... why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why), but still couldn't figure out what I want to accomplish.

How would I go about combining them? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `array3[i, j] = (byte)(array1[i, j] + array2[i, j]);`  Its addition - not sure where/how `filling in zeroes` comes into play

Comment: Weird, I tried that but didn't work. Restarted Visual Studio and now it works. By filling zeroes, I meant replacing all the zeroes where there is a 1 in the other array. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the output you want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array3.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < array3.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        // All you need to do is cast the int to a byte.
        array3[i, j] = (byte)((array1[i, j] == 0) ? array2[i, j] : array1[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Adding `array1[i, j]` and `array2[i, j]` could give you `2`, which is not wat you want in your example.

Comment: Glad I could help @m.o.