# Why does DateTime.DaysInMonth return a ushort?

Tags: c#, .net

I was just wondering why **DateTime.DaysInMonth(int, int)** returns an *int* instead of a *ushort*? I mean at worst it's 31 (for what the ushort is enough).

What am I missing?

Comment: We're not using 8 bit CPUs anymore...

Comment: Consider `byte` is not a number - it is one of memory unit, which can represent a number. So better suggestion will be why not `ushort`

Comment: I've marked as duplicate because I believe that the title of this question is different but the core concern is the same. I really believe that answers on the other question will drive OP to a right conclusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The type would not be CLS Compliant.
2. Typical hardware is optimized for `int` operations. That might be one of the reasons why operator overloads like `+(byte, byte)` or `+(short, short)` return an `int` and not a `byte` or `short`. Its arguable this is the only reason, consistent behavior with previous languages being another. You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why) for more details.

Comment: Well I believe the OP is most concerned about what's the reason behind not using `short` or any numeric type with less domain than `int`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer yeah, was adding to my answer to adress that concern.