# Memory management for int and short datatype in c#

Tags: c#

In c sharp what kind of memory related problem can occur if i use 'int' instead of 'short'? Is it a big mistake?

Comment: short is a data type representing 16-bit integers ,INT should be 32bit

Comment: no. using `int` instead of `short` is not a big mistake and its even more appreciated to use `int` which is more common rather than byte, short.... you wont face memory related problems unless your data is too big. just calculate. `int` is `4` bytes. see when you reach 2 giga bytes or more

Comment: I think it all depends on how you use it. If you are trying to create 1000s of lists, each stores the full range of shor/intt, You might see memory issues. It does not matter which type you use, one can run into memory issues if they are writing bad code.

Comment: This sound like we're trying to solve a problem you don't have.  [So - Asking a question : You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vast majority of cases, I wouldn't call using `int` instead of `short` a huge mistake (or even necessarily a mistake at all).

As other people have indicated, the main difference is that an `int` is 4 bytes and a `short` is just 2. In most cases, using `short` instead of `int` is a microoptimization; there are, of course, a few exceptions (e.g. you're working in a very memory-constrained environment, you're doing something that requires an enormous amount of memory and using short instead of int would result in a substantial memory saving, etc.).

This point may be a little more controversial, but in some cases using short rather than int could improve code clarity (if you're only expecting integers in a relatively small range), but that's usually not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, short can hold the numbers between -32,768 and 32,767. But integers can hold the numbers from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. The reason why the case is like that integers are 32 bit variables and shorts are 16 bit variables, i.e. integers occupy 4 byte in memory and shorts occupy 2 byte in memory. If you use short data type appropriately, you would save 2 byte memory in your computer during execution.

If you try to store a number that is greater than 32767 or lesser than -32,768, then there will be an overflow and you cannot reach your data correctly.

A tip: If you will store small numbers and you are sure that the value will not be greater than 32,767 ( loop variables may enter in this case ) you can use short and save 2 bytes of memory.

Comment: Save two bytes, waste two bytes when *reading* that data. 32-bit CPUs means they read 4 bytes at a time. The type's size should be selected based on business/domain requirements, not attempts to "save" memory

Comment: Different CPUs have different implementations. For example, in MIPS instruction set, there is an instruction "lb" which is "load byte". So you can even load 1 byte from memory to a CPU register.

Comment: .NET doesn't run on MIPS, but what you posted demonstrates the *waste*  of bandwidth

Comment: I know that .NET doesn't run on MIPS. I wanted to emphasize that we cannot comment on this subject without looking at whole instruction set of CPU and CPU specifications.

Comment: read up on here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why the question also applies to short

Comment: @ffguven what you posted just demonstrated the waste of bandwidth. What could load 4 bytes at once ends up loading just 1 or 2