# why adding 1 to byte.MaxValue results in 256 not an overflow

Tags: c#, overflow

I have this simple piece of code in C# to show overflow error when adding 1 to MaxValue of types.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte a = byte.MaxValue;
            byte b = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Max+1 is : {0}", a+b);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of overflow and a wrong result, it generates correct value: 256
Why? 
While maximum value of byte variable in C# is 255.
Am I wrong?

Comment: why should `string str = (255 + 1).ToString();` throw an error?

Comment: Adding `byte c = a + b;` seems to get to the bottom of how the addition is done: _"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"_ - it seems that `byte` is implicitly cast to an `int` for this addition.

Comment: You're just adding those two values and displaying them, you're not assigning them to a byte.

Comment: When you add bytes they are implicitly cast to ints. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why

Answer (score 3):

*Addition* on anything less than a `int` is done in `int`. This is described in the [Standard ECMA-334 C# specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) under *Numeric promotions*

**12.4.7 Numeric promotions**

> When overload resolution rules (§12.6.4) are applied to this set of
>   operators, the effect is to select the first of the operators for
>   which implicit conversions exist from the operand types. [Example: **For
>   the operation b * s, where b is a byte and s is a short, overload
>   resolution selects operator *(int, int) as the best operator**. Thus,
>   the effect is that b and s are converted to int, and the type of the
>   result is int. Likewise, for the operation i * d, where i is an int
>   and d is a double, overload resolution selects operator *(double,
>   double) as the best operator. end example]

Additionally, if you want to catch overflows you will need to use the [`checked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked) keyword

**Example**

```
byte a = byte.MaxValue;
byte b = 1;
byte c = checked((byte)(a + b));
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[checked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked)

> By default, an expression that contains only constant values causes a
>   compiler error if the expression produces a value that is outside the
>   range of the destination type. If the expression contains one or more
>   non-constant values, the compiler does not detect the overflow.
>   Evaluating the expression assigned to i2 in the following example does
>   not cause a compiler error.