# Why is the result of a subtraction of an Int16 parameter from an Int16 variable an Int32?

Tags: c#, .net, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [byte + byte = int… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)

I have a method like this:

```
 void Method(short parameter)
 {
     short localVariable = 0;
     var result = localVariable - parameter;
 }
```

Why is the result an `Int32` instead of an `Int16`?

Comment: BTW: which is the correct indefinite article? "an" or "a"?

Comment: Addition and subtraction of two values of any type T can give a result that doesn't fit into type T. Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927391/why-is-a-cast-required-for-byte-subtraction-in-c

Comment: This is effectively the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584, just with different types and a different operator.

Comment: I guess it's an, as Int32 begins with "I", but I'm not a native english speaker...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not just subtraction, there simply exisits no short (or byte/sbyte) arithmetic.

```
short a = 2, b = 3;
short c = a + b;
```

Will give the error that it cannot convert int (a+b) to short (c).

One more reason to almost never use short.

Additional: in any calculation, short and sbyte will always be 'widened' to int, ushort and byte to uint. This behavior goes back to K&R C (and probaly is even older than that).

The (old) reason for this was, afaik, efficiency and overflow problems when dealing with char. That last reason doesn't hold so strong for C# anymore, where a char is 16 bits and not implicitly convertable to int. But it is very fortunate that C# numerical expressions remain compatible with C and C++ to a very high degree.

Comment: It should be noted that this is part of the C#/CLI standard.

Answer (score 7):

All operations with integral numbers smaller than Int32 are widened to 32 bits before calculation by default. The reason why the result is Int32 is simply to leave it as it is after calculation. If you check the MSIL arithmetic opcodes, the only integral numeric type they operate with are Int32 and Int64. It's "by design".

If you desire the result back in Int16 format, it is irrelevant if you perform the cast in code, or the compiler (hypotetically) emits the conversion "under the hood".

Also, the example above can easily be solved with the cast

```
short a = 2, b = 3;

short c = (short) (a + b);
```

The two numbers would expand to 32 bits, get subtracted, then truncated back to 16 bits, which is how MS intended it to be.

The advantage of using short (or byte) is primarily storage in cases where you have massive amounts of data (graphical data, streaming, etc.)

P.S. Oh, and the article is "a" for words whose pronunciation starts with a consonant, and "an" for words whose pronunciated form starts with a vowel. A number, AN int. ;)

Comment: +1 Nice answer. (And deserves a bonus for your answer on the indefinite article. ;-))

Comment: Excellent, Kek444. You should add your answer to this related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why). I would definitely upvote it.

Comment: Small nitpick, they are "widened" rather than "rounded up". Integers don't require rounding to go to larger sizes, floats do.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are right, what I meant was that the number of bits was rounded up, while the number itself is widened. I'll clear it up.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers given within this thread, as well as the discussions given here are instructive:

(1) [Why is a cast required for byte subtraction in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927391/why-is-a-cast-required-for-byte-subtraction-in-c)

(2) [byte + byte = int… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why-c)

(3) [Why is a cast required for byte subtraction in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927391/why-is-a-cast-required-for-byte-substraction-in-c)

But just to throw another wrinkle into it, it can depend on which operators you use. The increment (++) and decrement (--) operators as well as the addition assignment (+=) and subtraction assignment (-=) operators are overloaded for a variety of numeric types, and they perform the extra step of converting the result back to the operand's type when returning the result.

For example, using short:

```
short s = 0;

s++;                // <-- Ok
s += 1;             // <-- Ok
s = s + 1;          // <-- Compile time error!
s = s + s;          // <-- Compile time error!
```

Using byte:

```
byte b = 0;

b++;                // <-- Ok
b += 1;             // <-- Ok
b = b + 1;          // <-- Compile time error!
b = b + b;          // <-- Compile time error!
```

If they didn't do it this way, calls using the increment operator (++) would be impossible and calls to the addition assignment operator would be awkward at best, e.g.:

```
short s
s += (short)1;
```

Anyway, just another aspect to this whole discussion...

Answer (score 1):

I think its done automatically done to avoid overflow,

lets say you do something like this.

```
Short result = Short.MaxValue + Short.MaxValue;
```

The result clearly wouldn't fit in a short.

one thing i don't understand is then why not do it for int32 too which would automatically convert to long???

Comment: It's not done to prevent overflow, more to discourage inefficient code. And it's inherited from C/C++

Answer (score 1):

The effect you are seeing...

```
short - short = int
```

...is **discussed extensively** in this Stack Overflow question: [**byte + byte = int… why?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why)

There is a lot of **good information** and some **interesting discussions** as to why it is that way.

Here is a highly-voted answer:

> I believe it's basically for the sake
>   of performance. (In terms of "why it
>   happens at all" it's because there
>   aren't any operators defined by C# for
>   arithmetic with byte, sbyte, short or
>   ushort, just as others have said. This
>   answer is about why those operators
>   aren't defined.)
>
> Processors have native operations to
>   do arithmetic with 32 bits very
>   quickly. Doing the conversion back
>   from the result to a byte
>   automatically could be done, but would
>   result in performance penalties in the
>   case where you don't actually want
>   that behaviour.
>
> -- Jon Skeet