# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got 3 variables all declared as type 'Int16', yet this code is refusing to work.

```
    private Int16 _cap;                 // Seat Capacity
    private Int16 _used;                // Seats Filled
    private Int16 _avail;               // Seats Available

    public Int16 SeatsTotal {
        get {
            return _cap;
        }
        set {
            _cap = value;
            _used = _cap - _avail;
        }
    }
```

Except the part where I have `_used = _cap - _avail;` is throwing this error, Error

> 1  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's because there's no subtraction operator for `short` (`Int16`). So when you write:

```
_cap - _avail
```

that's effectively:

```
(int) _cap - (int) _avail
```

... with an `int` result.

You can, of course, just cast the result:

```
_used = (short) (_cap - _avail);
```

Comment: Should you use `(short)` or `Convert.Int16()`?

Comment: Or for that matter, [any other arithmetic operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084668/why-is-the-result-of-a-subtraction-of-an-int16-parameter-from-an-int16-variable) either.

Comment: @Matthew I was just deleting my comment :-)