# Byte arithmetic: How to subtract to a byte variable?

Tags: java, byte

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to do somethink like this:

```
byte a = 23;
a = a - 1;
```

The compiler gives this error:
Test.java:8: possible loss of precision found   : int required: byte
             a = a - 1;
                   ^ 
1 error

Casting doesn't solve the error...
Why the compiler don't let me do it? 
Should I need to transform the variable 'a' into an int?

Comment: This has been asked hundred of times. See eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660856/promotion-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927391/why-is-a-cast-required-for-byte-subtraction-in-c/941677

Answer (score 6):

Do like this.

```
a = (byte)(a - 1);
```

When you subtract 1 from `a` then its integer value. So to get assign the result in byte you need to do explicit type casting.

Comment: Thanks! I applied the cast in the '1' instead of the result of the expression, that was my error. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

In Java math, everything is promoted to at least an `int` before the computation.  This is called [Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (JLS 5.6.2).  So that's why the compiler found an `int`.  To resolve this, cast the result of the entire expression back to `byte`:

```
a = (byte) (a - 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`a = a - 1;` // here before subtraction a is promoted to int data type and result of 'a-1' becomes int which can't be stored in byte as (byte = 8bits and int = 32 bits).

Thats why you'll have to cast it to a byte as follows :

```
a = (byte) (a - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
a -= 1;
```

You even don't need explicit cast, compiler/JVM will do it for you.

Should you change the variable type to int nobody can say, having only information you provided.

A variable type is defined by the task you are planning to perform with it.

If your variable a counts fingers on someone's hands, why would you use int? Type byte is more than enough for that.