# In C# assigning result of addition of two byte variables to another byte variable generates error, can be assigned only to int variable

Tags: c#, casting, int, byte, implicit-conversion

I have the following code -

```
using System;

namespace MyApp {
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        byte x = 10, y = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(y.GetType());
        //byte z = (x+y); Error: (9,14): error CS0266: 
        //Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. 
        //An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
        byte z = (byte)(x+y);
        Console.WriteLine(z.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
System.Byte
System.Byte
System.Byte
10
20
30
```

But instead of explicit type casting if `byte z = x+y` is used it generates the error -

```
(9,14): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

But as shown in the code, compiler reads `x` and `y` as byte.

So, why addition of two bytes is generating int requiring explicit type casting?

Comment: Because `x+y` is actually an `int`.  See [byte + byte = int… why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/941584/3744182) and [Why is a cast required for byte subtraction in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/927391/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of an [Implicit Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

This link explains further:

> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040310-00/?p=40323
>
> People complain that the following code elicits a warning:
>
> `byte b = 32; byte c = ~b; // error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'`
>
> "The result of an operation on 'byte' should be another 'byte', not an
>   'int'," they claim.
>
> Be careful what you ask for. You might not like it.
>
> Suppose we lived in a fantasy world where operations on 'byte'
>   resulted in 'byte'.
>
> `byte b = 32; byte c = 240; int i = b + c; // what is i?`
>
> In this fantasy world, the value of i would be 16! Why? Because the
>   two operands to the + operator are both bytes, so the sum "b+c" is
>   computed as a byte, which results in 16 due to integer overflow. (And,
>   as I noted earlier, integer overflow is the new security attack
>   vector.)
>
> Similarly,
>
> `int j = -b;`
>
> would result in j having the value 224 and not -32, for the same
>   reason.
>   ...
>    In our imaginary world, this code would return incorrect results once
>   the total number of games played exceeded 255. To fix it, you would
>   have to insert annoying int casts.
>
> `return ((int)captain.Wins + cocaptain.Wins) >=
>           ((int)captain.Games + cocaptain.Games) / 2;`
>
> So no matter how you slice it, you're going to have to insert annoying
>   casts. May as well have the language err on the side of safety
>   (forcing you to insert the casts where you know that overflow is not
>   an issue) than to err on the side of silence (where you may not notice
>   the missing casts until your Payroll department asks you why their
>   books don't add up at the end of the month).

Comment: int x = 2147483647; int y = 2147483647; int z = x+y; This will result in overflow as well. So why nobody is worried here? @paulsm4

Comment: Because Raymond thinks that int overflows are normal.  The liability of being a C++ programmer ;)